# Improve Speed of website (On the Openshift platform)

Tags: memcached, openshift, infinispan, cloudflare

I have an application that is gaining a lot of users quickly. It is a website set up with cartridges PHP 5.4, MongoDB 2.4, MySQL 5.5, RockMongo 1.1 and Cron 1.4.

What are the best ways of monitoring so I can evaluate what is slowing the site. I would like to know this so that I can see what I should improve.

I have come up with 3 options so far:

-Cache the calls to the sever, Memcached and Infinispan are 2 that I found

-Increase the gear size, currently small.

-Use a CDN, possibly Cloudflare

Are there any options that I have missed and what should I take into account when deciding what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a scaled application so that the number of web gears in use would go up as you get more traffic.  If you do that, you should use a medium or large gear for the database.

Comment: I looked at this but the site uses cake php which is not scalable. Is there a way to set the gear to be medium/large always?